# CanCan: User not being able to view own stuff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, sorcery

I made a simple role based auth with Sorcery and Cancan, which database holds a column named ROLE that when registering a user can be admin or normal,

Relato is a scaffold where you can create "Reports" i wanted to normal user can only see those created by himself and do other stuff(update,destroy) as well.

my ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)

 if user.role == 'admin'
  can :manage, :all
 elsif user.role == 'normal'
   can :create, Relato
   can :manage, Relato, :user_id => user.id
   can [:read, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id

 end
```

no need for control protection

in my view index.html.erb where it lists all "reports" i put

```
<% if can? :index, Relato %> 
<tbody>
<% @relatos.each do |relato| %>
  <tr class="alt">
    <td><%= relato.cliente.name %></td>  
     <td><%= relato.projeto.name %></td>  
      <td><%= relato.local_id %></td>  
      <td><%= relato.task_id %></td>  
      <td><%= relato.time %></td>  
     <td><%= relato.comment %></td>  
    <td><%= relato.isdoe %></td>  
       <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_relato_path(relato) %></td>  
      <td><%= link_to 'Deletar', relato, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work, the user can't see his reports, using admin account everything is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't can [:show, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id be can [*:read*, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id

Comment: Changed to what you said, but it didnt worked T_T

Comment: @MarsAtomic is correct. However that is a separate bug and won't fix what your are asking here.

Comment: Could you please help me? how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using :manage as well as adding specific permissions for each CRUD action? Try removing the manage symbol and see what happens. At the very least, you're DRYing up your code.

Comment: Wow, I totally misread that, didn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a collection of `@relatos`, you should not rely on a instance of `Relato` to check the ability.

Consider using something like `can?(:index, Relato)`. Notice that I'm using the class.

Now you can setup the ability, but since the class is being used, you cannot check check attributes like `user_id`.

Since you have `can :manage, :all` for admin, they should be able to read the `@relatos`.

Let me know if you were trying to achive something else.

Comment: I think he indented to check of the class but it's a typo. A good approach would be to authorize relatos on the controller level with  [load_and_authorize_resource](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions)

Comment: The controller is definitely the best place. I just don't see a point on checking the `user_id` of a collection. What he needs is to have tests in place to make sure the queried `@relatos` can be readable by the user.

Comment: Thats what `load_and_authorize_resource`  does.

Comment: i'm trying to do this, but first i need to understand how to set up ability, cause, putting load_and... is showing me erros when creating a new Relato.

Comment: The [original CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) does not work with Rails 4 since the author kind of fell of the off the face of the earth and stopped maintaining it. Use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) instead.

Comment: Removed Original Gem and installed the CanCanCan one, used ur exemple maxcal, but still not working  as it should, i'm too new in Rails to figure out whats the problem T_T. my view for index.html.erb = <%= if can? :index Relato %>

Comment: @maxcal Yes, he can use `load_and_authorize_resource` with `index`, but to work it properly he needs a `accessible_by` scope in `Relato`.

Comment: RPinel, how to do that, can you explain like i'm five? please, i'm really lost in rails, this is my first time at it and im learning thru fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if can? :read, Relato %>
```

Not `@Relatio`.

Also you might want to consider using cascading abilities. Simply put an admin gets all the abilities of a normal user. Plus he gets some special admin abilities. To show why this is a good idea imagine if realize that you also need a editor role:

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.role == 'admin'
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.role == 'normal'
    can :create, Relato
    can :manage, Relato, :user_id => user.id
    can [:show, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id
  elsif user.role == 'editor'
    can :manage, Relato 
    can [:show, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id
  end
end
```

Thats alot of duplication. Instead:

```
def initialize(user)

  # Anybody can change their profile
  can [:show, :update, :destroy], User, :id => user.id

  # Anybody can edit Relatos they own.
  can :manage, Relato, :user_id => user.id

  if user.role == 'admin'
    can :manage, :all
  end

  if user.role == 'editor'
    can :manage, Relato
  end
end
```

Comment: Changed editor to normal, but what is editor_id about, i'm too dumb or do i need a column in relatos table which record the user? Also, normal is now able to see all relatos, he wasn't able to see any before editig like you said. is a progress i think, thanks.

Comment: I guess that was kind of a stupid example. I was thinking along that a user could assign an editor to a Relato to allow another user to edit it.

Comment: My main point was that in role based auth you often have a has many relation between users and roles (a user can be a commenter and a forum_moderator etc). Cascading privileges lets you do that without going insane.

Comment: i put an authorize! :read, @relato at relatos controller and for the 'normal' user it's denied access, but admin still can use it. So, there are a problem in ability for sure...